# JAXB what should be returned from `beforeMarshal(Marshaller)` method?

Tags: java, jaxb

First of all, I'm not talking about [Marshaller#Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.Listener.html).
I'm talking about those `class defined` event callbacks.

Can anybody tell me what should be returned from `boolean beforeMarshal(Marshaller)` method?

```java
/**
 * Where is apidocs for this method?
 * What should I return for this?
 */
boolean beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller);
```

I mean, anyway, to use this method for converting `JPA's Long @Id to JAXB's String @XmlID` **with JAXB-RI** and **without MOXy**.

[edited]
a `void` version seems working though. is this just an documentation problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer**

The `boolean` return type is a documentation error.  The return type should be `void`.

**Long Answer**

> I mean, anyway, to use this method for converting JPA's Long @Id to
>   JAXB's String @XmlID

You could use [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as it does not have the restriction that a field/property annotated with `@XmlID` be of type `String`.

> with JAXB-RI and without MOXy.

You could use an `XmlAdapter` to map support your use case:

**IDAdapter**

This `XmlAdapter` converts the `Long` value to a `String` value to meet the requirements of the `@XmlID` annotation.

```
package forum9629948;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class IDAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseLong(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Long value) throws Exception {
        return DatatypeConverter.printLong(value);
    }

}
```

**B**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to specify the `XmlAdapter`:

```
package forum9629948;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IDAdapter.class)
    private Long id;

}
```

**A**

```
package forum9629948;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    private B b;
    private C c;

}
```

**C**

```
package forum9629948;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)public class C {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlIDREF
    private B b;

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum9629948;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);

        File xml = new File("src/forum9629948/input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        A a = (A) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(a, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Input/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a>
    <b id="123"/>
    <c b="123"/>
</a>
```