# JPA Long @Id as JAXB @XmlID generates XSD validation error

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb, jpa-2.0

I've implemented a REST API based on JPA and JAXB.

I have a classes roughly like this (very simplified):

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
...
public class Thing {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    ...
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JAXBLongAdapter.class)
    private Long id;
    ...
}
```

Hibernate (my current JPA provider) generates numbers as the id value, but they are naturally unique only for one one type, Thing in this example.

Now XSD says that xsd:id (@XmlID) is a NCString which cannot be a plain number so i prepended a '_' to numbers in the JAXBLongAdapter. - like '_1'

Now the schema validator complains:

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-id.2: There are multiple occurrences of ID value '_1'.]
```

If I understand this correctly a xsd:ID element must have a (string) value that is globally unique in the xml document. But this is very opposite of the common way of using IDs in databases.

What do I do now?
I thought of three things:

- Create a JAXBLongAdapter for each type with a type specific prefix?
- Using another JPA id generator, perhaps UUID? - But which one?
- Stop using @XmlID and @XmlIDREF, which creates redundancy and general messiness.

It seems that I now have to change the Database schema to use different IDs.
 - But it would be nice if the IDs stayed short, because they appear in URLs.

My question: Is there a ID generator that is comparably fast and is globally unique?
Or is there another way of tackling this?

EDIT:

This hack kinda works, leaving the JPA IDs intact.

```
@XmlID
@XmlAttribute(name="id")
private String getXmlID(){
    return String.format("%s-%s", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), this.getId().toString());
}

private void setXmlID(String xmlid){
    String prefix = String.format("%s-", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    if(xmlid.startsWith(prefix)){
        this.id = Long.parseLong(xmlid.substring(prefix.length()));
    }else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(xmlid+" does not look like "+prefix+"###");
    }
}
```

By moving the JAXB Annotation from the field to dedicated private getters/setters for the XmlID.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629948/jaxb-what-should-be-returned-from-beforemarshalmarshaller-method

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what I had done with for some time.

You can ask yourself what is actually `@XmlID` for this domain object when marshalled?

I once thought `@XmlID` and `@XmlIDREF` can solve the circular problem in JAXB.

Here comes what I'm doing with my JPA entities along with JAXB annotations.

Do not give the `simple JPA @Id` up. That's the heart of JPA.

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @XmlAttribute
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @XmlElement(name = "child")
    @XmlElementWrapper
    private Collection<Child> children;
}


@XmlRootElement
public class Child {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Long getParentId() {
        return parent.getId();
    }

    @Id
    @XmlAttribute
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @XmlTransient // for preventing infinite circular problem
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! - So you stopped using the ID and IDREF features in favor of "manual" references by id. - How do you reconnect  the objects during unmarshal? Do you use some kind of factory or adater ?

Comment: I actually don't have to reconnect them. Parent and the Child is very different and unique domain objects. Each JAX-RS resources work solely for Parent or Child. Because Parent.id and Child.id is Unique in DB, my EntityManager finds them only with those Ids. When I find the Child with its id there is already parent field set.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**WHAT THE ANSWER SHOULD BE**

The answer should be to use the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation on both the `@XmlID` and `@XmlIDREF` properties.  Unfortunately the JAXB RI does not leverage that combination, and EclipseLink MOXy only leverages it for `@XmlID`.  I have entered the following MOXy bug, which we could fix if you are interested in this approach:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/386569

**Employee**

```
package forum11791735;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

    @XmlID
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JAXBLongAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name="long")
    private Long id;

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlSchemaType(name="long")
    private Employee manager;

    @XmlElement(name="report")
    private List<Employee> reports;

}
```

**WORK AROUND**

The error you are seeing is appears to be due to schema validation.  Is it possible for you to disable schema validation or set a `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` to ignore these errors?

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

**ALTERNATIVES**

If you are using `@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF` to map bidirectional relationships then you may be interested in MOXy's `@XmlInverseReference` extension:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the rigorous insight! - In the Schema in the bug report it looks like I "loose" the semantic information of the ID/IDREF pair in the XSD universe? - Or is there no special semantic connected to those types? My idea involved easier client generation for other languages but I'm stating to doubt this becomes reality. I'd like to keep validation though.

Comment: If I'm willing to give up the ID/IDREF meaning and reimplement this manually using some kind of reference proxy in xml - is there a clean way to do this with the JAXB standard tools? This would probably also solve my reference-to-external-to-xml-jpa-entity issue, maybe..